# Easiest way to send log from heroku node.js script to my iPhone

Tags: node.js, heroku, push-notification

I have a node.js script running in Heroku that does a check every 30 seconds. If various parameters are true, an action is triggered. It could be a couple of days between actions, but also a couple of minutes.
I log these actions locally, but I would like to receive a message on my iPhone when the action is triggered. I could send an email or write a simple app and send push messages but is there an easier way?

These messages would be a simple text to notify only me. What do you guys use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Pushover](https://pushover.net/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this https://elements.heroku.com/addons/pushwoosh. It's free for a single application with unlimited push notifications.